# Не загружает аватарку на сайте в джанго

Tags: python, django

В консоли пишется ошибка о том, что нет файла в `/media/users_images/`, хотя он там есть

> `[13/Aug/2023 14:42:46] "GET /media/users_images/3da7f88a6a2c4707ab9cac24bd0523d0_3BCavl8.png HTTP/1.1" 404 2602.`

Чем может быть вызвана такая проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Все файлы твоего проекта блокируются самим джанго, за исключением файлов css. Нужно настроить доступ.
Идешь в settings и указываешь внешний путь:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'uploads'
MEDIA_URL='/my-media/'
```

MEDIA_URL - по какому пути ты будешь обращаться с сервера к компьютеру
MEDIA_ROOT - путь, в котором следует искать изображения
uploads - моя папка с изображениями
далее заходишь в urls проекта и импортируешь

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
```

добавляешь к urlpatterns, вот пример:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('feedback.urls')),
    path('gallery/', include('gallary.urls'))
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```